# Override or Disable CDI integration with Bean Validation

Tags: java, cdi, interceptor, bean-validation, websphere-liberty

As far as i know, in JEE7 Bean Validation is automatically integrated with CDI.
For example if i use a CDI container, i don't need to inject and use a javax.validation.Validator to check if my bean violate some constraint.
So, i don't need to do something like this:

```
@Inject
Validator validator;

... 

SoccerPlayer player = new SoccerPlayer();
    player.setFirstName(firstName);
    player.setLastName(lastName);
    player.setAge(age);

Set<ConstraintViolation<SoccerPlayer>> violations = validator
            .validate(player);
```

But the following SoccerPlayer bean

```
public class SoccerPlayer {

@NotNull
@Size(min = 5)
private String firstName;

@NotNull
@Size(min = 5)
private String lastName;

@Max(50)
@Min(value=16, groups = GoalKeeper.class)
private int age;

private String position;

public SoccerPlayer() {
}

// Getters and setters omitted 
}
```

could automatically validate with @Valid annotation.

```
public class SoccerPlayerProcessor {    

    public void processPlayer(@Valid SoccerPlayer player){
        // Do stuff with the player.
    }   
}
```

Now in this case i can't use groups in conjuction with @Valid annotation, to diversify validation behaviour.

So, is there any method to achieve my goal?
Or as an alternative, could i disable CDI integration with bean validation? Could i override default CDI javax.validation.Validator with my custom implementation?

I'm using WebSphere Liberty profile as application server.

Thank you in advance.

**EDIT**:

To be more accurate, this is an extract from: https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/validator/5.1/reference/en-US/html/validator-integration.html#section-integration-with-cdi

> As of version 1.1, Bean Validation is integrated with CDI (Contexts
>   and Dependency Injection for JavaTM EE).
>
> This integration provides CDI managed beans for Validator and
>   ValidatorFactory and enables dependency injection in constraint
>   validators as well as custom message interpolators, traversable
>   resolvers, constraint validator factories and parameter name
>   providers.
>
> Furthermore, parameter and return value constraints on the methods and
>   constructors of CDI managed beans will automatically be validated upon
>   invocation.
>
> **When your application runs on a Jave EE container, this integration is enabled by default.**

My question is, is there any method to disable this default behaviour? Or in alternative can i override default CDI interceptor? Or is it impossible?

Comment: What do you mean by "i can't use groups in conjuction with `@Valid` annotation"?

Comment: I mean what about if i would like to validate SoccerPlayer with GoalKeeper.class group? AFAIK i can't do something like @Valid(groups=GoalKeeper.class). If i could override default Validator, i could annotate my API with custom annotation (for example Validate which has groups field @Validate(groups=GoalKeeper.class)) and in the Validator i could collect all the bean annotated with it and perform validation with specific group.

Answer (score 2):

Try using [@ConvertGroup](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/beanvalidation/api/javax/validation/groups/ConvertGroup.html) to achieve the desired outcome.

Building on your previous example the code would look like this.

```
public class SoccerPlayerProcessor {    

    public void processPlayer(@Valid @ConvertGroup(from=Default.class, to=GoalKeeper.class) SoccerPlayer player){
        // Do stuff with the player.
    }
```

If you need more than one @ConvertGroup, use [@ConvertGroup.List](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/beanvalidation/api/javax/validation/groups/ConvertGroup.List.html) to hold multiple @ConvertGroup annotations for the same element.

Comment: I would recommend to use validator.forExecutables().validateParameters(..) method in your unit test to check, if your validation works as it should.